# Custom 404 redirect for a site with URL rewriting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

In my site, I have used IIS7's URL rewrite module to redirect URLs like http://mysite.com/File.aspx?Name=SomeName into http://mysite.com/SomeName.

It appears that IIS7 has created a corresponding rule check, so that any URL of the sort http://mysite.com/SomeURL is redirected to File.aspx. This is fine in most cases, when the URL is correctly rewritten.

The problem is that in some cases, the file no longer exists - http://mysite.com/SomeName2 will still get redirected to http://mysite.com/File.aspx?Name=SomeName2.

I want to show a custom 404 error page for this URL - how do I trigger the 404 error in global.asax (I have set application error logging and handling in global.asax)? The below code doesn't work.

```
Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://mysite.com/Invalid-File.aspx?" & Request.QueryString.ToString)
```

It just shows the ugly default IIS 404 error page. Adding a customerror in web.config doesn't help.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a status code you need to prevent IIS taking over based on your new error code, make sure to set [`Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx?ppud=4) like this:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://mysite.com/Invalid-File.aspx?" & Request.QueryString.ToString)
```

Comment: For some reason the page isn't redirecting to Invalid-File.aspx - the File.aspx page continues to be displayed! 

Response.Redirect results in the redirected page having a 302 error :(

Comment: This is weird - on using your code, the page contents displayed are from File.aspx, but the headers state the code as 404, and the location as Invalid-File.aspx!

Comment: @Wild - What do you *want* the result to be?  A 404 to the client shouldn't be happening if you're redirecting to actual content, that's what a 301 or a 302 is for.  Are you trying to do something closer to a `Server.Transfer()` on the response?

Comment: I want it to be a 404. The file in question doesn't exist.

Edit: To clarify, your above code would work great - *if* the actual redirect to the custom 404 page had worked - it doesn't.

Comment: Oh shit! Didn't notice the part about server.transfer until now! It works! Yay!

Comment: @Wild - Try `HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("~/Invalid-File.aspx");` for the last line of the answer above, this will keep the URL the user has, but render the contents of your 404 page.

Comment: Hi Nick, it works this way even without the httpcontext.current. The URL is the missing page, but the content is shown from the 404 page. The headers are 404 - perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the 404 error page in the IIS admin equal to what you're specifying in the web.config? I wonder if .net isn't jumping into the pipeline at the right time.

Comment: The custom 404 page is already present in IIS admin in the .Net error pages section for.

Comment: So you changed the setting in IIS Manager > IIS > Error Pages? I'm not talking about the .Net Error Pages - this just changes your web.config.

Comment: I see - can you please clarify what you meant?

Comment: Make sure you have a 404 entry in IIS Manager > IIS > Error Pages that matches the 404 entry you have in IIS Manager > ASP.NET> .NET Error Pages

Comment: Aah, I see - now it makes sense. In any case my global.asax App_Error is getting triggered before the IIS 404 error page can be displayed (I tried setting it where you have mentioned). To trigger a 404, I tried accessing doesntexist.aspx, which bypasses the URL rewrite (files with .aspx extensions are excluded).

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially use the Application_Error method and then do a response.redirect to the required page with the correct status code

Comment: Hi,

Application error isn't triggering, since the page is being redirected to http://mysite.com/File.aspx?Name=Somename - IIS7 doesn't realize the page doesn't exist.